# How do i setup a default controller or hide the controller name using asp.net MVC2

Tags: controller, routes, asp.net-mvc-2

On my project I have only one controller so I want to do this:

```
http://www.example.com/{action}/{optional id}
```

All actions will be of a defined controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the path templates in the Global.asax

there will be something like

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // route
new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }); // defaults
}
```

to change to something like

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{action}/{id}",
new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
}
```